# XML/SWF help needed

Tags: xml, flash

I'ld like to make a little swf application to use it on my XP desktop place.

And I'ld like to run movies directly from this swf.
So, I need to know parameters like movie name and subtitle name to parse it to the button link.

And I thought that if I create an XML file to contain all data (1db for .avi,.mpeg etc and other from .srt,.sub files) I can parse the selected data to flash and create that button link - Use: to see all movies on my desktop and control swf with my remote control.

Does anyone knows how can I put all the movies and subtitles addresses in an XML file ?
Note: My database is very big, no chance to put it all manualy.. so I need a button like.. refresh database to recreate the XML file every time a new movie is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want to use subtitle for .flv file, actualy I don't want to use it at all in flash.
I just want to use it on my localhost, local hdd.
I need to create dynamicaly a link to do this getURL ("  file:// --sub-file= ).

For this, I want to use a menu (controlable by my IR remote) to select 
first, the movie path
second, the subtitle path

After selection, to select  and execute the link ("  file:// --sub-file= ).

It's a basic logic used, very easy to understand.

So, my question is - how can I make another two menus,
one containing all my movies and
one contaning all my subtitles
so that, I can select from the first menu, a movie - from the second, a subtitle.

I cannot make all the links manualy cause on my hdd drive I have like 500 movies.
Now, I thought that .XML world is best to help me.
It can be a win program, anything - the thing that can turn my empty .xml file in 2 .xml files with this structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding='UTF-8'?>
<movies>

<movie1>Path to movie 1</movie1>
<movie2>Path to movie 2</movie2>
```

// etc.

```
</movies>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding='UTF-8'?>
<subtitles>

<sub1>Path to sub 1<sub1>
<sub2>Path to sub 2</sub2>
```

// etc.

```
</subtitles>
```

but what is? Do you know something to help me?
Like I said, I cannot do this manualy.
I need a program or something to search for me all the .avi, .mpeg, .vob, .3gp, .mkv files etc. and add all the found results in the first XML file. The same thing for subtitles, .sub, .srt etc - and insert the results in the second XML file.

I thought that a manual sync is easier that an automatic one. I don't want to use any PHP script cause I'll run this things on my home desktop used only for playing music, videos and gamepading - no internet connection, nor I don't want to use wamp or something else cause I think is harder and lots of head akes.
Now, with my 2 XML as 2 databases, I can take the info from here and use it in my flash and do whatever I'ld like to.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a server side language to build your XML files dynamically, so they never needs to physically exists, nor you need to update them.

About how to place subtitle information inside a XML file, that's no problem at all: XML doesn't care about what you gonna do with those content, it's just describe your content. This way we can say XML is a metalanguage: a language to describe other languages.

Bottom line: you can structure your XML file anyway you want.

This links can help you:

- [Creating subtitles for flash video using XML](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/518/1/Creating-subtitles-for-flash-video-using-XML/Page1.html)
- [Subtitle format comparison](http://www.annodex.net/node/8) (to choose a subtitle file format)